# "Your Graphviz installation could not be found" python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, graphviz

Hi I'm currently trying to install one my offices django projects. when i try to 'pip install -r requirements.txt' i get the error "Your Graphviz installation could not be found" even though it is installed locally on my machine. This is causing python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1. I have no idea whats wrong, i'm also a designer so this isnt the easiest thing to troubleshoot for me. I'm on a mac also.